# Traversing single linked list not working why?

Tags: c, linked-list, traversal

im starting to learn data structures and i tried to making a simple program about a single linked list.

> The problem is that when i call my *display function* (transversing the list) **it doesn't give me an output?** What is wrong with my code and how do i fix this?

This my program:

```
int main(){

int n;
        
printf(" Input the number of nodes : ");
scanf("%d", &n);

create(n);

printf("\n Data entered in the list : \n");
display();
```

}

```
void create(int n)
{   
struct node *head=NULL;
int data, i;

head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

if(head == NULL)                         
{
    printf(" Memory can not be allocated.");
}
else 
{
    printf(" Input data for node 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    head->data = data;      
    head->next = NULL; 

    for(i=1; i<n; i++) // Creating n nodes 
    {
       struct node *current = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // addnode
        if(current == NULL)
        {
            printf(" Memory can not be allocated.");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" Input data for node %d : ", i);
            scanf(" %d", &data);

            current->data = data;      
            current->next = NULL;    
            head->next = current;
            
            head = head->next; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

My Traversing function:

```
 void display(struct node *head)
 {
 struct node* ptr = head;

 if(head == NULL)
 {
    printf(" List is empty.");
 }
 else
 {
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf(" Data = %d\n", ptr->data);     
        ptr = ptr->next;                     
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: You should be getting compiler warnings since you call `display()` (with *no* arguments) but define `void display(struct node *head)` as taking one argument. Are you putting all the shown code in a single source file, or using multiple source files?

Comment: The `head` variable created in `create()` only exists inside that function. You need to return it to the caller and use it later in `display()`. (But you have an issue where you modify it at `head = head->next;` so if you `return head` it won't be correct).

Comment: Fix create() by replacing `current->next = NULL;` with `current->next = head;`. Replace `head = head->next;` with `head = current;`

Comment: Your question makes it evident that you are not using a debugger. It is imperative to know how to use one. You should learn the debugger basics *before* playing around with actual programming.

Comment: thank you guys i appreciate the answer and advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are lines in `create()`

```
head->next = current;
head = head->next;
```

this operation set `head` to `current`. Note that `current->next` is NULL. As result the entire content of the list is lost except the last element.

Just replace those lines with:

```
current->next = head;
head = current;
```

This will put the `current` node at the top of the list.
Remember to return `head` from `create()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    struct node {
        int data;
        struct node * next;
    };

    struct node * create(int n) {   
        struct node *head=NULL;
        int data, i;
        struct node * ptmp = NULL;
        head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(head == NULL) {
            printf(" Memory can not be allocated.");
        } else {
            printf(" Input data for node 1 : ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            head->data = data;      
            head->next = NULL; 
            ptmp = head;
            for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
                struct node *current = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // addnode
                if(current == NULL) {
                    printf(" Memory can not be allocated.");
                    break;
                } else {
                    printf(" Input data for node %d : ", i);
                    scanf(" %d", &data);
    #if 0

                    // insert first
                    current->data = data;      
                    current->next = head;    
                    head = current;

    #else

                    // insrt last
                    current->data = data;
                    current->next = NULL;
                    ptmp->next=current;
                    ptmp = current;

     #endif

                }
            }
        }
        return head;
    }

    void display(struct node *head)
    {
        struct node* ptr = head;
        if(head == NULL) {
            printf(" List is empty.");
        } else {
            while(ptr != NULL) {
                printf(" Data = %d\n", ptr->data);     
                ptr = ptr->next;                     
            }
        }
    }

    int main() {

        int n = 0;
        printf(" Input the number of nodes : ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
            if (n<=0 || n > 6400) {
                printf("Invalid input : %d (Enter value in range 0-6400)\n", n);
                return 0;
            }
        struct node * head = create(n);
        printf("\n Data entered in the list : \n");
        display(head);
    }
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.